# Allow Week days in Date Picker in Obj C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

I am using ActionSheetDatePicker, I can select four datePickerMode i.e.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIDatePickerMode) {
    UIDatePickerModeTime,           // Displays hour, minute, and optionally AM/PM designation depending on the locale setting (e.g. 6 | 53 | PM)
    UIDatePickerModeDate,           // Displays month, day, and year depending on the locale setting (e.g. November | 15 | 2007)
    UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime,    // Displays date, hour, minute, and optionally AM/PM designation depending on the locale setting (e.g. Wed Nov 15 | 6 | 53 | PM)
    UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer, // Displays hour and minute (e.g. 1 | 53)
} __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
```

There is no option to display week days in Picker, Can somebody help me, how can I display week days including date, month and year, excluding time in date picker.

I am working in obj C.

Thanks!

Comment: can you link that third party?

Comment: https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0

Comment: + (instancetype)showPickerWithTitle:(NSString *)title
           datePickerMode:(UIDatePickerMode)datePickerMode
             selectedDate:(NSDate *)selectedDate
              minimumDate:(NSDate *)minimumDate
              maximumDate:(NSDate *)maximumDate
                doneBlock:(ActionDateDoneBlock)doneBlock
              cancelBlock:(ActionDateCancelBlock)cancelBlock
                   origin:(UIView*)view;
Using this method to trigger datepicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to modify your datasource. you need three things day, date,month and year. You can use [NSDateComponents](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdatecomponents) to separate date into these components, and once your month increases or decreases, you need to modify data source again.

```
ActionSheetStringPicker showPickerWithTitle:@"Select Date"
                                    rows://add your data source here
                        initialSelection:0
                               doneBlock:^(ActionSheetStringPicker *picker, NSInteger selectedIndex, id selectedValue) {
                                  NSLog(@"Picker: %@, Index: %@, value: %@", 
                                  picker, selectedIndex, selectedValue);
                                }
                             cancelBlock:^(ActionSheetStringPicker *picker) {
                                  NSLog(@"Block Picker Canceled");
                                }
                                  origin:sender];
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this hope it helps

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

NSArray* weekdays = [dateFormatter shortWeekdaySymbols];
```

Comment: used it, this is not working, as I am using a library class ActionSheetDatePicker, written above in question.

Comment: I want to display dates in Date Picker